# How to rewrite implicit joins to explicit joins?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm having some trouble re-writing these JOINS using explicit joins.  I'm trying to understand how this is accomplished.  Here is the original query using implicit joins that I've inherited:

```
FROM prod.f31122 t,
       prod.f4801   wo,
       prod.f30008  r,
       prod.f0101   ab
WHERE t.wtdoco = wo.wadoco(+)
   and t.wtmmcu = wo.wammcu(+)
   and t.wtmmcu = r.iwmcu
   and t.wtan8 = ab.aban8
```

I've tried the following, but I'm getting different result sets.  The same count, but the result set is incorrect (likely an issue with my groupings which aren't displayed).  Here is my translation using explicit joins:

```
FROM prod.f31122 t      
JOIN prod.f4801 wo ON t.wtdoco = wo.wadoco
JOIN prod.f4801 wo ON wo.wammcu = t.wtmmcu 
JOIN prod.f30008 r ON t.wtmmcu = r.iwmcu 
JOIN prod.f0101 ab ON t.wtan8 = ab.aban8
```

I just want to make sure that my translation from implicit joins to explicit joins is logically correct (for my education and understanding).  For the record, I can keep the implicit joins, but I am just trying to understand this process better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
FROM prod.f31122 t      
LEFT JOIN prod.f4801 wo ON t.wtdoco = wo.wadoco AND wo.wammcu = t.wtmmcu 
JOIN prod.f30008 r ON t.wtmmcu = r.iwmcu 
JOIN prod.f0101 ab ON t.wtan8 = ab.aban8
```

You join to `wo` only once, and the two join conditions appear in the same `ON` clause, with the logical operator `AND` between them.

`LEFT JOIN` can also be written as `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, and `JOIN` can be written as `INNER JOIN`. I prefer these longer phrases since they are more explicit.

Comment: Sorry, this was actually the correct answer.  The LEFT OUTER JOIN returned a different result set.  Just using LEFT JOIN returned what I needed.  Thanks for this solution.

Comment: @dgibbons82 - I am not sure I understand. Are you saying that you found a case where `LEFT OUTER JOIN` produces a different result than `LEFT JOIN`? I very strongly doubt that; more likely, you made a mistake somewhere. If in fact that is true, you may want to file a bug report with Oracle. If it is an example that can be reproduced and you can post it here, that would be extremely interesting.

Answer (score 4):

This is not quite correct.

1. Multiple join criteria are implemented with one instance of the table and AND conditions
2. The `(+)` is the old Oracle syntax for outer joins. JOIN on its own defaults to INNER JOIN so you need to correct that.

So it should look like this:

```
FROM prod.f31122 t      
LEFT OUTER JOIN prod.f4801 wo ON t.wtdoco = wo.wadoco
                              AND t.wtmmcu = wo.wammcu
JOIN prod.f30008 r ON t.wtmmcu = r.iwmcu 
JOIN prod.f0101 ab ON t.wtan8 = ab.aban8
```

Answer (score 3):

This part is wrong:

```
FROM prod.f31122 t      
JOIN prod.f4801 wo ON t.wtdoco = wo.wadoco
JOIN prod.f4801 wo ON wo.wammcu = t.wtmmcu
```

You use AND to do two things on a single join, not two separate JOINs. For example:

```
FROM prod.f31122 t      
LEFT JOIN prod.f4801 wo
    ON t.wtdoco = wo.wadoco and wo.wammcu = t.wtmmcu
```

Using "JOIN" twice would literally join the same table two separate times, so you would have two copies of all the fields based on the different join conditions.

**Corrections**

Per @MathGuy & @AaronDietz comments I switched this to a LEFT JOIN due to the (+) presence in the question.

Comment: Your answer is wrong in the same way the OP's was - the join to `wo` must be an **outer** join.

Comment: I guess I'm forgetting something, haven't used that style of join in a very long time.  Why does it translate to left outer join?  Wouldn't the equals conditions remove the [t] rows if they were not met?

Comment: The `(+)` denotes outer join